# There is another way to optimize this bubble-sort?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, optimization, bubble-sort

I have this code which sort a numeric array using bubble sort algorithm.

```
var a = [34, 203, 3, 746, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9];

function bubbleSort(a)
{
    var swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
            if (a[i] < a[i+1]) {
                var temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
}

bubbleSort(a);
alert(a);
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/x7VpJ/

Well, it works perfect as you can check, but I wondered if there is another way to optimize this to do fewer loops using the actual method. I mean, using *swapped* variable.
Maybe omiting the sorted items... some idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: choose the algorithm you may like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: I think this is as optimal as a bubble sort can get. Of course, bubble sort is a very bad sorting algorithm and far from optimal

Comment: you can give a try to Bogosort algorithm, it's exactly what you need

Comment: Any reason you're not using `a.sort()`? (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

Comment: looks like an assignment may be...

Comment: @svidgen you shouldn't link to w3fools. Use mdn or something simulare. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: OK but again, why is anyone using a manual sort in Javascript? You should be using the built-in sort - it runs in compiled code and will generally outperform anything you can write yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that I was looking for:

```
var a = [34, 203, 3, 746, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9, 1, 32423, 3455, 23, 4234,23];

function bubbleSort(a)
{
    var swapped;
    var n = a.length-1;
    var j = 0;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < n; i++) {
            if (a[i] < a[i+1]) {
                var temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        n--;
    } while (swapped);
}

bubbleSort(a);
alert(a);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x7VpJ/1/

Thanks all responses.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of different sorting algorithms in JS.  I made a page that compares sorting times and from what I noticed "Quick" seems the best option.

Bubble Sort:

```
var arrBubble= new Array();
var tmpBubble;
function srtBubble(){
    tmpDate=new Date();
    timBegin=tmpDate.getTime();

    var blnBubbleSwitch;
    do {
        blnBubbleSwitch=false;
        for(var i=0;i<arrBubble.length-1;i++){
            if(arrBubble[i]>arrBubble[i+1])
            {
                tmpBubble=arrBubble[i];
                arrBubble[i]=arrBubble[i+1];
                arrBubble[i+1]=tmpBubble;
                blnBubbleSwitch=true;
            }
        }
    } while(blnBubbleSwitch);
}
```

Insertion:

```
var arrinsertion= new Array();
var tmpinsertion;
function srtinsertionion(){
    var j;
    blninsertionSwitch=false;
    for(var i=0;i<arrinsertion.length;i++){
        tmpinsertion=arrinsertion[i];
        j=i;
        while((j>=0)&&arrinsertion[j-1]>tmpinsertion)
        {
            arrinsertion[j]=arrinsertion[j-1];
            j--;
            //blninsertionSwitch=true;
        }
        arrinsertion[j]=tmpinsertion;
    }
}
```

Shell:

```
function srtShell(){
var arrShell= new Array();
    for (var h = arrShell.length; h = parseInt(h / 2);) {
        for (var i = h; i < arrShell.length; i++) {
            var k = arrShell[i];
            for (var j = i; j >= h && k < arrShell[j - h]; j -= h)
                arrShell[j] = arrShell[j - h];
            arrShell[j] = k;
        }
    }
}
```

Quick:

```
function srtQuick()
{
    var arrQuick= new Array();
    qsort(arrQuick, 0, arrQuick.length);
}
function qsort(array, begin, end)
{
    if(end-1>begin) {
        var pivot=begin+Math.floor(Math.random()*(end-begin));

        pivot=partition(array, begin, end, pivot);

        qsort(array, begin, pivot);
        qsort(array, pivot+1, end);
    }
}
Array.prototype.swap=function(a, b)
{
    var tmp=this[a];
    this[a]=this[b];
    this[b]=tmp;
}
function partition(array, begin, end, pivot)
{
    var piv=array[pivot];
    array.swap(pivot, end-1);
    var store=begin;
    var ix;
    for(ix=begin; ix<end-1; ++ix) {
        if(array[ix]<=piv) {
            array.swap(store, ix);
            ++store;
        }
    }
    array.swap(end-1, store);

    return store;
}
```

Merge:

```
function merge_inplace(array, begin, begin_right, end)
{
    var arrMerge= new Array();
    for(;begin<begin_right; ++begin) {
        if(array[begin]>array[begin_right]) {
            var v=array[begin];
            array[begin]=array[begin_right];
            insertion(array, begin_right, end, v);
        }
    }
}

function insertion(array, begin, end, v)
{
    while(begin+1<end && array[begin+1]<v) {
        array.swap(begin, begin+1);
        ++begin;
    }
    array[begin]=v;
}

function msort(array, begin, end)
{
    var size=end-begin;
    if(size<2) return;

    var begin_right=begin+Math.floor(size/2);

    msort(array, begin, begin_right);
    msort(array, begin_right, end);
    merge_inplace(array, begin, begin_right, end);
}

function srtMerge()
{
    msort(arrMerge, 0, arrMerge.length);
}
```

Built in JS Sort:

```
function srtJSSort()
{
    var arrJSSort= new Array();
    arrJSSort.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
}
```

Of course I would suggest using your arrays outside of the function so you can continue using it after the data is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

If I stick with the original question (and I will not suggest completely different algorithms...).

Yes, there is another improvement - bi-direction bubble sort, called [shaker sort](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/40270/Shaker-sort). It eliminates problem of turtles and rabbits. In one-directional bubble sort light bubbles are moving fastly towards the end of the array (rabbits), while the heavy bubbles are moving towards the start very slowly. But if you sort in bi-directional manner, both types of bubbles are sorted pretty fast (still in O(n^2), but usually faster than with the conventional bubble sort).