# JavaScript sorting without modifying DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, sorting

I started learning JavaScript a week ago and I made a sorting function on my own. It does work but it requires that I modify the DOM nodes, is there a way to sort the nodes without changing the `innerHTML`?

```
<body>
<ul id="list">
    <li>Art</li>
    <li>Mobile</li>
    <li>Education</li>
    <li>Games</li>
    <li>Magazines</li>
    <li>Sports</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var myList = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
var a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    a[i] = myList[i].innerHTML;
}
a.sort();
for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    myList[i].innerHTML = a[i];
}
```

Output:

- Art
- Education
- Games
- Magazines
- Mobile
- Sports

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bx3Q2/3/)

This works well,

Comment: This is not a code review site. See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Your code seems to work fine, nothing for us to fix...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Code Review, and should be migrated.

Comment: [I swear I've seen JS sorting question before.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15956018/1618257)

Comment: @DavidStarkey You seem to misunderstand what the OP is doing, it's not simple array sorting, they are trying to sort a NodeList, it doesn't work exactly the same way

Comment: @JuanMendes Looks to me like they take all the `<li>` from a `<ul>` and put it into an array (`a`).  They sort it, then re-write the `<li>` tags.  Are you seeing something else?

Comment: @DavidStarkey The question is likely about a better way to do it, how to actually sort the nodes without recreating DOM elements

Comment: Here's an alternative way to do it http://jsfiddle.net/bx3Q2/8/

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks, it works great and yes my question actually was how to sort the nodes without recreating DOM elements, which i didn't mention, so sorry about that.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand See my comment, I'm trying to reopen the question, I've reworded it so it's a good SO question.

Comment: @JuanMendes This was my first post and i absolutely had no idea. Anyways thanks for your help :)

Comment: @JuanMendes, okay.  I voted to reopen. Just note that performance wise, `innerHTML` is proven to be the fastest method of modifying a HTML page.